# Using Cucumber + Webrat and a Button gives me a no connection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, webrat

This is the cucumber command (Works with other forms I have been testing):

```
And I press "Save"
```

This is the error message:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:53:in `timeout'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:845:in `post'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
```

This is the haml code:

```
- semantic_form_for current_user, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| .actionbuttonbar
    %p.actionbutton
      = f.submit 'Save', { :class => "actionbutton" }
```